# REACT-JS - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: api, react

Problema em renderizar meu state sempre da o erro:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
>
> Check the render method of `Main`. See
>   https://fb.me/react-warning-keys for more information.
>
> ```
> in li (at main/index.js:42)
> in Main (at App.js:14)
> in header (at App.js:12)
> in div (at App.js:10)
> in App (at src/index.js:7)
> ```

**code:**

**

```
render(){     
    return( 
        <ol className="planetas-list">
            {this.state.Planetz.map(planetas =>(                
                <li key={planetas.lista}> 
                    {planetas.PlanetzClima} 
                </li>                   
         ))}
        </ol>  
    )
  }
}
```

**

Poderiam me dizer o que está acontecendo ? Ja procurei bastante no overflow mas mesmo assim não consegui resolver... vlw!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

É um problema comum. Todos os itens de uma lista renderizada deve conter uma propriedade chamada `key` e ela deve ser única( ou seja, não pode ter outra key igual).

Eu vi que no seu código você colocou `<li key={planetas.lista}>`, mas é provável que não seja única.

Tenta colocar o `ID` de cada item ai.

Em último caso vc pode usar o index:

```
render(){     
  return( 
      <ol className="planetas-list">
          {this.state.Planetz.map((planetas, index) =>(                
              <li key={index}> 
                  {planetas.PlanetzClima} 
              </li>                   
       ))}
      </ol>  
  )
}
}
```

Mas não é recomendado pelo Facebook:

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may
> change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues
> with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an
> in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a
> key. If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then
> React will default to using indexes as keys.

Você pode dar uma olhada na documentação para saber mais detalhes: https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Boa sorte!

Comment: Obrigado irmão! to quebrando a cabeça aqui mas vou me aprofundar na doc do react e qualquer dúvida eu posto aqui, se alguém puder responder fico grato!

Comment: você verificou se o `planetas.lista` é um valor único?

Comment: Consegui resolver retirando do meu state todos os {} que estavam se repetindo e adicionando id's únicos a cada propriedade que eu chamei no render. vlw rapaziada!

Comment: Alguém sabe explicar porque esse warning é acusado ao usar a função .map() sem atribuir a propriedade key e não quando se cria uma <View> diretamente (também sem especificar a key)?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a pergunta, vou tentar responder.
Key é um atributo string especial que você precisa definir ao criar listas de elementos.
Os keys ajudam o React a identificar quais itens sofreram alterações, foram adicionados ou removidos. As chaves devem ser atribuídas aos elementos dentro do array para dar uma identidade estável aos elemento.

Answer (score -2):

No meu caso, resolvi da seguinte maneira com Typescript, mas da quase no mesmo! (No componente pai):

```
const App = () => {
const [selectPriority, setSelectPriority] = useState("")


const alternarPrioridades = (priority?: any) => {
    setSelectPriority(priority)
}

return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="page-wrapper">

        {showAddEditModal ? (
          <Modal children={ AddEditTaskForm(selectPriority, alternarPrioridades) } />
        ) : null }
        
      </div>
    </div>
)
}
export default App
```

No componente filho:

```
const AddEditTaskForm = (selectPriority: string, alternarPrioridades: (priority?: any) => void) => {

return (
    <ul className="priority-buttons">
        {["high", "medium", "low"].map((priority) => {

        if (selectPriority === priority) {           <------- A MÁGICA PARA FAZER SELECIONAR SOMENTE AQUELE QUE O USUÁRIO CLICAR ESTÁ NESSE IF-ELSE
          return (
          <li key={priority} className={classNames(`${selectPriority}-selected`, priority)} onClick={ (e) => alternarPrioridades(priority)}>
            {priority}
          </li>
          )
        }else {
          return (
          <li key={priority} className={classNames(``, priority)} onClick={ (e) => alternarPrioridades(priority)}>
            {priority}
          </li>
          )
        }

        })}
    </ul>
)

export default AddEditTaskForm
```

Claro que o código fica um pouco grande, mas esta foi a única forma que encontrei para resolver este problema!

Comment: Por favor, leia com bastante atenção ao post [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/137387)