# Problema de "chave" Única React

Tags: javascript, array, react, aplicação-web, react-dom

Estou tentando criar um jogo de xadrez usando React. Tô indo muito bem, exceto por este erro. Este é meu código:

```
import "./style.css";

function App() {

  const squares = []; //squares order

  for (var i=0; i<8; i++) {

  for (var j=0; j<8; j=j+2) { //appending squares rows starting with a white square
    squares.push('sqr w')
    squares.push('sqr b')
  }

  for (var h=0; h<8; h=h+2) { //appending squares rows starting with a black square
    squares.push('sqr b')
    squares.push('sqr w')
  }}

//create square component
  const squareItem = squares.map(square => {
    return (
      <div className={square}/>
    )
  })

  return (
    <div className="tab">
        {squareItem}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

A mensagem de erro é esta:
**Warning: Each child in a list shoud have a unique "key" prop**

O que eu faço?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [REACT-JS - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/389572/react-js-warning-each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resumir, o React pede que seja passado uma prop `key` para todo componente que esteja dentro de uma lista.

Segundo a própria documentação do React

> As chaves ajudam o React a identificar quais itens sofreram alterações, foram adicionados ou removidos. As chaves devem ser atribuídas aos elementos dentro do array para dar uma identidade estável aos elementos:

no seu caso basta fazer dessa forma:

```
const squareItem = squares.map((square, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index} className={square}/>
    )
  })
```

Referências:

[Listas e Chaves - React](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)