# Para que serve e como definir a prop "key" no React?

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Ao renderizar uma lista dinâmica no React ou React Native, recebo o seguinte aviso:

> Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Apesar disso, as coisas parecem funcionar bem sem a prop `key`. Veja [este exemplo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pokemon-list-without-keys-r87j6):

```js
function shuffleArray(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex],
      array[currentIndex]
    ];
  }

  return array;
}

function App() {
  const [pokemons, setPokemons] = React.useState([
    {
      name: "Bulbasaur",
      img: "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/001.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Ivysaur",
      img: "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/002.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Venusaur",
      img: "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/003.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Charmander",
      img: "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/004.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Charmeleon",
      img: "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/005.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Charizard",
      img: "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/006.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Squirtle",
      img: "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/007.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Wartortle",
      img: "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/008.png"
    },
    {
      name: "Blastoise",
      img: "https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/detail/009.png"
    }
  ]);

  function shuffle() {
    setPokemons(shuffleArray([...pokemons]));
  }

  return (
    <ul>
      <button onClick={shuffle}>Embaralhar</button>
      {pokemons.map((pokemon) => (
        <li onClick={() => console.log(pokemon.name)}>
          <img src={pokemon.img} alt={pokemon.name} />
          <span>{pokemon.name}</span>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
ul {
  padding-right: 2rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: #deebff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

span {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Para resolver esse aviso, já encontrei várias respostas aqui utilizando o índice como `key`, então tenho as seguintes dúvidas:

- Para que serve essa propriedade `key`?
- Eu preciso definir uma `key` somente ao percorrer um array?
- Como posso definir uma chave? Posso utilizar o índice, um número aleatório ou tem outro jeito melhor?

Comment: Antes que venham as respostas, quero deixar claro que o objetivo aqui é criar uma pergunta canônica, não apenas resolver o aviso. Assim, esta pergunta poderá ser referenciada quando este problema for notado em outra pergunta do site (como já o vi diversas vezes).

Comment: Será que os motivos são os mesmos que o Angular e Vuejs? Se sim, talvez seja melhor remover a palavra React? Já que a intenção é criar uma canônica.

Comment: @Danizavtz, nesse caso eu acho que seria melhor ter uma canônica para cada biblioteca (ou framework, hehe), já que cada um pode ter as suas respectivas peculiaridades, de modo que pode ficar confuso fazer tudo em uma resposta só. :-) Mas claro que isso está para o AP decidir.

Comment: @Danizavtz qual são as razões de utilizar em angular e vuejs?

Comment: Rafael Tavares a resposta dada por mim falta alguma coisa?

Comment: @novic Sua resposta está boa, inclusive votei nela. Se quer deixar completa, acho que poderia mencionar o motivo da `key` impactar o desempenho (eu expliquei brevemente [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/514307/100416)), isso também explicaria o porquê de comportamentos inesperados que você mencionou; e acho que faltou esclarecer melhor quando pode-se usar índices como chave. Por exemplo, uma lista gerada a partir de um array que não muda a ordem, nem insere itens no começo/meio e nem remove, não tem problemas em usar o índice, o motivo está explicado na resposta que linkei.

Comment: @novic Relendo minha resposta, vi que é importante citar também o perigo no uso de chaves instáveis, como o `Math.random()` ou `new Date()`

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [REACT-JS - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/389572/react-js-warning-each-child-in-a-list-should-have-a-unique-key-prop)

Comment: @LeoBrescia está relacionada, mas não responde. Responde (mais ou menos) apenas ao segundo ponto (_Eu preciso definir uma key somente ao percorrer um array?_), e só responde este por causa da resposta, a pergunta está mal escrita e só quer resolver o erro.

Answer (score 7):

> Para que serve essa propriedade `key`

Para identificar de forma única cada elemento ou componente que vai ser criado, alterado, excluído e/ou selecionado a partir de uma lista de valores (`array`), ou seja, está vinculado a criação de elementos dinâmicos de uma lista qualquer que necessitam ter unicidade.

> Eu preciso definir uma `key` somente ao percorrer um `array`?

***Na verdade a pergunta correta: Ao utilizar um `array` para criar elementos dinâmicos é preciso utilizar um identificador único (`key`)***?

Sim, quando for criar elemento ou componente é necessário a passagem de um identificador para que o `React` sabia quais elementos foram criados, alterados, excluídos e/ou selecionados.

De uma forma geral é como o `React` verifica as modificações em seus elementos de forma exata para que no final o desempenho não seja comprometido, mas, não é só isso que faz com que o `React` tenha um melhor desempenho, existindo mais técnicas para que isso aconteça.

A ressalva da pergunta e que `key` somente é utilizado na criação de elementos dinâmicos a partir de um `array`. Um `array` pode ter outros fins como por exemplo: filtros, criação de novos `arrays` e nesse momento não utilizando `key` do componente.

> Como posso definir uma chave? Posso utilizar o índice, um número aleatório ou tem outro jeito melhor?

Não é ideal utilizar o índice de um `array` para identificar os elementos ou componentes e o motivo predominante é que pode acontecer mudanças na ordenação desses valores (que englobam qualquer mudança nesse `array` como inserções de novos valores, exclusões de itens da lista e mudanças de ordem) que pode impactar no desempenho e renderizações sem necessidade, causando lentidão e erros. Se a sua lista não sofrer nenhum dessas ações citadas até pode utilizar o índice do `array` como uma unicidade (*particularmente prefiro não usar*), por exemplo, uma lista de exibição de valores que não sofre nenhuma modificação e só vai servir de exibição.

Em uma lista que os itens tem uma identificação única como por exemplo `id` de uma tabela de banco de dados ou algum repositório é muito recomendado a sua utilização, outro forma é utilizar códigos em pacotes prontos como por exemplo [uniqueid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uniqueid) e [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid), gerando também nesse caso uma identificação plena de cada elemento.

Não use códigos que possam causar ou ter chance de causar duplicidade e com isso quebrando o motivo principal de existir a chave para identificar qual elemento foi modificado.

***Referencias***

- [React - keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)
- [Index as a key is an anti-pattern](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)
- [ReactJS | Keys](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-keys/#:%7E:text=A%20%E2%80%9Ckey%E2%80%9D%20is%20a%20special%20string%20attribute%20you,an%20identity%20to%20the%20elements%20in%20the%20lists.)
- [How to get “key” prop from React element (on change)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070997/how-to-get-key-prop-from-react-element-on-change)
- [Why do we need Keys React?](https://www.educba.com/react-keys/)

Edição REACT 18

Existe agora um nova maneira de gerar `id` aleatório e único na versão ***18*** do [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) com o `hook`: `useId()`, ***exemplo***:

```
import { useState, useId } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'name 1',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'name 2',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'name 3',
    },
  ]);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {items && items.map((item) => <li key={useId()}>{item.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ou seja, na chave `key` chame `useId` (`key={useId()}`) que vai gerar um valor aleatório e identificar unicamente esse componente criado.

***Referencia:*** [An Introduction to the useId() Hook in React 18](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/the-useid-hook-in-react-18-take-a-look-19a6c2f645bc)