# Erro no React.js - Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, react, warnings

Olá, devs!

Estou usando Vite e Reactjs com Typescript.

Estou com a seguinte mensagem de erro no console do chrome:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Check the render method of `Home`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
    at O2 (http://127.0.0.1:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/styled-components.js?v=b6ed82b3:1422:6)
    at Home (http://127.0.0.1:5173/src/pages/Home/index.tsx?t=1660967399653:28:45)
    at Routes (http://127.0.0.1:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=b6ed82b3:1157:5)
    at Router (http://127.0.0.1:5173/src/router.tsx?t=1660967680051:27:7)
    at div
    at App
    at Fe (http://127.0.0.1:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/styled-components.js?v=b6ed82b3:1377:40)
    at AuthProvider (http://127.0.0.1:5173/src/contexts/auth/index.tsx?t=1660966053104:23:3)
    at Router (http://127.0.0.1:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=b6ed82b3:1104:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://127.0.0.1:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=b6ed82b3:1233:5)
```

Pesquisando na documentação descobri que seria necessário definir uma `key={X.toString()}`, substituindo o `X` pelo id, index ou valor único do elemento!

Porém eu não conseguir encontrar onde é pra definir essa chave única.

Segue código do `Home.tsx`:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [selectedGenre, setSelectedGenre] = useState<Genre>(mockedGenres[0]);
  const filteredGames: Game[] = mockedGames.filter((elem) => elem.genreId === selectedGenre.id);
  const actualDate = DateTime.now();
  const formatedDate = `${actualDate.weekdayShort}, ${actualDate.day} ${actualDate.monthLong} ${actualDate.year}`;

  return (
    <Styled.HomeContainer>
      <Menu path="home" />
      <Styled.HomeContentContainer>
        <Styled.HomeContentHeader>
          <Styled.TitleContainer>
            <h1>
              smartize <br /> store
            </h1>
            <p>{formatedDate}</p>
          </Styled.TitleContainer>
          <Styled.SearchInputContainer>
            <div>
              <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <input placeholder="pesquise aqui" />
          </Styled.SearchInputContainer>
        </Styled.HomeContentHeader>
        <section>
          <Styled.GenreBar>
            <Styled.GenreSelectButton>Todos</Styled.GenreSelectButton>
            {mockedGenres.map((elem) => {
              return (
                <Styled.GenreSelectButton active={elem.name === selectedGenre.name} onClick={() => setSelectedGenre(elem)}>
                  {elem.name}
                </Styled.GenreSelectButton>
              );
            })}
          </Styled.GenreBar>
          <Styled.GamesHeaderContainer>
            <div>
              <p>Escolha seus jogos</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Ordem:</p>
              <Styled.GamesOrderSelect>
                <option>Mais vendidos</option>
                <option>Mais baratos</option>
                <option>Mais caros</option>
              </Styled.GamesOrderSelect>
            </div>
          </Styled.GamesHeaderContainer>
          <GamesList list={filteredGames} />
        </section>
      </Styled.HomeContentContainer>
      <OrderDetails />
    </Styled.HomeContainer>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Segue link da documentação do React sobre o assunto: https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: é só você colocar o `key` no código: `mockedGenres.map((elem, index) =>` no retorno `<Styled.GenreSelectButton key={index}` etc ... aqui no site já tem um resposta para isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/514407/para-que-serve-e-como-definir-a-prop-key-no-react

Comment: Isso, na verdade a forma ideal de utilizar o key seria botando o id do próprio item,  sendo essa uma boa prática, mas nessa situação o index deve funcionar da mesma forma.

Comment: Como o ___@novic___ disse ali nos comentários, o método ___map()___ tem dois parâmetros (element, index) que você pode passar na sua arrow function e passar pro componente como __key={index}__.

Comment: Obrigado, colegas! Acabei descobrindo como resolver e foi quase como o @novic disse! Coloquei `key={elem.name.toString()}`, já que o nome é um do gênero é único!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal seria que o `mockedGenres` tivesse um id, pois essa `key` que ele reclama deve ser algo único entre cada elemento que está sendo retornado do map.

Mas assumindo que não tenha id, você pode adicionar para que tenha ou usar uma estratégia de gerar um valor aleatório que seja `único` e passar na `key`

Isso ajuda para que o `React` saiba quando re-renderizar algo ou não

```
<Styled.GenreBar>
        <Styled.GenreSelectButton>Todos</Styled.GenreSelectButton>
        {mockedGenres.map((elem) => {
          return (
            <Styled.GenreSelectButton key={elem.id} active={elem.name === selectedGenre.name} onClick={() => setSelectedGenre(elem)}>
              {elem.name}
            </Styled.GenreSelectButton>
          );
        })}
      </Styled.GenreBar>
```

Comment: Sim, mano! Foi isso que acabei descobrindo! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Encontrei a solução!
Usando o `name` como `key`(por ser um dado único em cada gênero), no `<Styled.GenreSelectButton>`, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
{mockedGenres.map((elem) => {
          return (
            <Styled.GenreSelectButton
key={elem.name.toString()}
active={elem.name === selectedGenre.name}
onClick={() => setSelectedGenre(elem)}>
             {elem.name}
            </Styled.GenreSelectButton>
          );
        })}
```

O que aprendi foi que, é necessário ter uma `key` sempre que usar algum tipo de lista no `React`, utilizando um dado único de cada elemento, como por exemplo o `id`, no meu caso o nome dos gêneros.

Muito obrigado a todos!